# Code working in jsFiddle but not in browser

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I'm trying to run the following code, written on my local machine:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/WShdx/3/

Functionality-wise (ignore the broken images in the previous and next buttons, and the wrongly-sized main images) the click/hover function is working properly in jsfiddle. However, on my local machine it's not working at all.

For all intents and purposes the code is identical, except the local copy has this head section to load in the javascript/css files that are contained within the jsfiddle page:

```
<head>
  <title>Jquery Wizard</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="wizard.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
```

Is there some wonderful function of jsFiddle that is making my code magically work, or am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working at all?  What kind of errors is your debugger reporting?

Comment: Give us something, error or anything, at this point there is no way to tell why it doesn't work. Is your external js is in the same folder? Do you have to use https, try http for jquery cdn instead. Try to run it through the validator.

Comment: It seems possible that this is a security issue; online code has different permissions in different browsers than local code, particularly with respect to access from various domains.

Comment: Sorry guys didn't see these comments. As stated above, the issue is that the click/hover jquery function isn't working when not in jsfiddle. I've uploaded the files here: http://harrisonfjord.com/wizard/index.html . Dr.Molle appears to be right, it may have something to do with the onLoad in jsFiddle, but I'm not 100% sure. EDIT2: Yep, Dr Molle was right, see below. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You chose to run the script-code "onload" on jsFiddle, that's the difference.

Without onload it will not find `$('area')` , because your script is placed inside the `<head>`, where the elements inside the `<body>` are still unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Got it working, appreciate it. I got it working by adding "$(window).load(function(){<rest of the jquery>}". If anyone else has the same problem, this function waits until the rest of the page has loaded before running. As Dr Molle said, my script wasn't working because it was running before the page had loaded, and was looking for elements that hadn't been created yet.

Comment: It's also possible to simply place thze script at the end of the body. The benefits: all elements are known there and ! the script is loaded later, so it's possible that the page itself will be shown faster.

Comment: Remember, you can always load a draft (ctrl+shift+Enter) and see the source code generated by jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I'd also advice anyone who run into such errors to use firebug or any debugging tool debug the script whenever such problems occur. Might be very simple yet frustrating problems like an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error. Debuggers come in very handy!