# jQuery .each works in jsFiddle but not in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to work with jQuery's `$.each` function, and can't seem to get it to work.  I'm testing the output with alerts, but no matter what I change the selector to in the `$('selecter').each`, nothing seems to happen.  My console is devoid of errors as well.  I've tried div's, spans, etc..and nothing seems to work.  I'm including jQuery 1.10 from the Google CDN, and I made sure that is included before I try to run this code.

The weird thing is that I can get the code to work perfectly in a jsFiddle.  Anyone have any ideas as to why this wouldn't be working in my page?

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cuZV9/

Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchDropdown option").each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id = "searchDropdown">
    <option value = "5, 2, 0, 1"> Cycle(5, 2, 0, 1) </option>
    <option value = "6, 3, 0, 3"> Utility(6, 3, 0, 3) </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you running with `$(document).ready` or the like?

Comment: Are you putting your code in a "ready" handler or a window load handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code working in jsFiddle but not in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637873/code-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-browser)

Comment: Yes I am.  The code in the jsFiddle is the exact code I have on my website, so if you look in the fiddle you'll see that I have the $.each within my $(document).ready function

Answer (score 1):

You are running the code before the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

Put your .each function in a document.ready(function() {}) syntax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchDropdown option").each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
}
```

**Thanks to all the comments**

Comment: There are multiple `option`s within the unique `select`, ID is fine.

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP is selecting all the options from the first dropdown element, so there are multiple options

Comment: ahhh my bad, let me edit it remove the negative after edit please

Comment: The document does not need to be _rendered_, the DOM just needs to be _ready_  that are two different things.

Comment: Too early in the morning out here, better now?  :D

Comment: Well the DOM can be manipulated before it is fully loaded ;). At the time a script is executed you can already manipulate the DOM but only at the `ready` event it is guaranteed that the DOM was fully loaded.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function()/*remove this space*/{
    $("#searchDropdown option").each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```