# Javascript works on jsfiddle but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to develop a phonegap app for quite some time now, and I'm stuck at something.

This is my code, and it is supposed to work (I tested on jsfiddle) but it doesn't on my app. Can anyone give me a hint?

```
$(".singleProfileImage").on("click", function() {
    console.log('Clicked');
    $("#share").css("display","block");
});
document.addEventListener("deviceready", share);
document.addEventListener("resume", share);
function share() {
    $("#email").on("click", function() {
        window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaEmail('http://www.rejicast.com/node/'+nid);
    });
    $("#whatsapp").on("click", function() {
        window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('http://www.rejicast.com/node/'+nid);
    });
}
```

It doesn't work with or without the deviceready and resume events. The thing is, I have to use deviceready or I can't use the socialsharing plugin.

Comment: It should work. How can this work in jsfiddle without the plugin? Have you ensured that the plugin is loaded correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I left out what I mean. It's clicking on images that works on jsfiddle but not on mobile.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What errors do you get? Which bits don't work? What happens instead? How are you loading the JS into the page? Does your Console show any messages? Does your Net tab show all the resources loading correctly?

Comment: Almost certainly a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637873/code-working-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-browser) but there isn't enough code in the question to tell for sure.

Comment: I click on .singleProfileImage, and nothing happens. Nothing in console. The net tab shows the icons loading perfectly.

Comment: When and where doesn't work? If you are testing in mobile devices try replacing 'click' event with 'vclick'.

Comment: I connect the device via USB, go to chrome://inspect, click Inspect and type the script there. Oddly enough, clicking on the image works; but on the device itself, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, also I checked `vlick` and read it's a jQuery Mobile event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the structure of the file a bit and also realised that if something comes undefined, scripts stops hence clicking on image not working.